# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' attribute error in django

Tags: python, django

This is the views.py

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
content = forms.CharField(label="content",widget=forms.Textarea,required=True)


def edit(request, title):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EditForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/page.html", {

            "title": title,
            "content": util.get_entry(title)
        })



else:
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form":EditForm(content)
    })
```

This is urls.py

```
path("wiki/<str:title>/edit", views.edit, name="edit")
```

This is util.py,according to the project this was not to be changed.

```
    def list_entries():
```

"""
Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
"""

```
_, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))

def save_entry(title, content):
```

"""
Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
it is replaced.
"""

```
filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))

def get_entry(title):
```

"""
Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
entry exists, the function returns None.
"""

```
try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

This is edit.html

```
    % extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="/wiki/{{ title }}/edit" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the error:
*

```
Internal Server Error: /wiki/harsha1/edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\wiki\encyclopedia\views.py", line 91, in edit
    "form":EditForm(content)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 973, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 376, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 134, in __str__
    return self.as_table()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 277, in as_table
    errors_on_separate_row=False,
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 195, in _html_output
    top_errors = self.non_field_errors().copy()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 306, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 172, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 386, in _clean_fields
    value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
  File "C:\Users\harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 258, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
[22/Aug/2020 12:18:10] "GET /wiki/harsha1/edit HTTP/1.1" 500 173523
```

- 

i am getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' attribute error when i go to the /title/edit route.I am new to django please be elaborate, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show util.py ?

Comment: I have added util.py

Comment: @HarshaMupparaju Please provide the full error log.

Comment: Suggest printing something before the "return None" in the get_entry function.

Comment: @mohammedwazeem added the full error log

Comment: in views.py l 91 => test "form":EditForm({'content':content})

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms

> To bind data to a form, pass the data as a dictionary as the first
> parameter to your Form class constructor:

In docs :

**forms.py :**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
data = {'subject': 'hello',
         'message': 'Hi there',
         'sender': 'foo@example.com',
         'cc_myself': True}
 f = ContactForm(data)
```

---

in your code, edit form :

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
content = forms.CharField(label="content",widget=forms.Textarea,required=True)
```

So:

```
content = util.get_entry(title)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form":EditForm({'content',content})
    })
```